# Current location of UIImageView in its super UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview

i have add an UIImageView to a UIview dynamically, and change its position through touches, now i want to find the current position of the UIImageView...
any suggestions.?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the frame property of the view.